# How to setting two apps in one domain NGINX?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nginx, nuxt.js

I have two apps.

- Landing page (Nuxt.js)
- Main Apps (Laravel Vue)

I got problem when I setting the NGINX. Everytime I enter the LaravelVue Apps, the assets always not found because its always access root in nuxtjs.

How to configure it?

My nginx look like this

```html
server {

        server_name mydomain.com;

        #nuxt
        location / {
                root /var/www/html/nuxt;

                proxy_pass http://localhost:8006;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        #laravel&vue
        location /client {
                root /var/www/html/laravue/public;

                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

        }

        location /dashboard {
                root /var/www/html/laravue/public;

                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                 root /var/www/html/laravue/public;

                 try_files $uri =404;
                 fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                 fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
                 fastcgi_index index.php;
                 fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                 include fastcgi_params;
         }


}
```

Thanks

Comment: what about changing laravel's application path in .env file. set it to `mydomain.com/client`

Comment: Welcome to SO ... you need to change `asset` base url in laravel